# Restrict duplicate entries in json localstorage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I went through few link, but that didnt help me. I have to restrict duplicate titles in json array. What is way to do here??

```
function submitForm(){
  var titleInput=document.getElementById('titleName').value;
  var messageInput=document.getElementById('titleDesc').value;  
  var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];
  var newItem = {
                    "title":titleInput ,
                    "desc": messageInput
                };

  if(!(titleInput=="" || messageInput=="")){
    oldItems.push(newItem); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!(titleInput == "" || messageInput == "")) {
       var repeated = false;
       for (var i = 0; i < oldItems.length; i++) {
           if (oldItems[i].titleInput == titleInput) {
               repeated = true;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (repeated == false) {
           oldItems.push(newItem);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check wheter the item is there before adding it.

```
var alreadyExists = oldItems.some(function (item) { return item.title == titleInput; }); 

if(!(titleInput=="" || messageInput=="") && !alreadyExists) {
    oldItems.push(newItem); 
}
```

Then perhaps you should make the concept more explicit by encapsulating that logic within an ItemStore or something similar.

```
function ItemStore(items) {
    this._items = [];
    this._titleMap = {};

    this.addAll(items || []);
}

ItemStore.prototype = {
    constructor: ItemStore,

    hasItemTitled: function (title) {
        return !!this._titleMap[title];
    },

    add: function (item) {
        var title = item.title;

        if (this.hasItemTitled(title)) throw new Error("the store already contains an item titled '" + title + "'");
        this._titleMap[title] = true;
        this._items.push(item);
    },

    addAll: function (items) {
        items.forEach(this.add.bind(this));
    },

    items: function () { return this._items.slice(); }

    //other useful methods such as itemAt, remove...
};
```

Then your code becomes as simple as...

```
  var titleInput=document.getElementById('titleName').value;
  var messageInput=document.getElementById('titleDesc').value;  
  var oldItems = new ItemStore(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || []);
  var newItem = {
      "title":titleInput ,
      "desc": messageInput
  };
  var shouldAddItem = titleInput != "" && messageInput !="" && !oldItems.hasItemTitled(newItem.title);

  if (shouldAddItem) oldItems.add(newItem);
```

Now obviously, your function is still doing too much since it:

- knows how to retrieve and create a new item from the user's input
- knows how to rehydrate the item store
- knows what to check to validate if an item is valid and should be added or not

You should be reading about the [Single Responsability Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which isin't only applicable in OO.